# ohmyzsh: command not found: truffle | unable to migrate via truffle

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, truffle

I am trying to follow along the [chainlink "Build, Deploy and Sell Your Own Dynamic NFT" according to the chainlink docs](https://blog.chain.link/build-deploy-and-sell-your-own-dynamic-nft/), however, whenever I come to migrate the truffle dependencies, the zsh command is not found.  I have the following set in both `/Users/alexsingleton/.oh-my-zsh` and the `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

, yet, whenever I run the truffle migration (ie `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby`), the terminal output reports it as unfound (ie `zsh: command not found: truffle`).  Do I need to add additional parameters to my bash-profile or oh-my-zsh configuration file in order to successfully run the truffle migrations?  I'd sincerely appreciate any guidance- thanks!

Comment: Did you logout and back in, or reload the startup file, after making these edits?

Comment: Confirmed- ran `npm install` before running `truffle migrate --reset --network rinkeby` but still the same error: `zsh: command not found: truffle`.

Comment: @alexanderjsingleton : Since it is clear from the error message, that your PATH is broken, you need to check the PATH at the place where you actually run your _truffle_ program. Showing the `export` statement for the PATH, which can be anywhere else, is not really helpful.

Comment: Thank you- does this answer your question?  I am running the truffle migration file from the following path: `/Users/alexsingleton/Desktop/random-nft/dungeons-and-dragons-nft`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple reinstall of Node-js remediated my issue- if encountering the subject error, simply run:

- `nvm install node --reinstall-packages-from=node`

If the above doesn't work, check-out this [post by Byte Archer](https://bytearcher.com/articles/ways-to-get-the-latest-node.js-version-on-a-mac/) for other ways to reinstall or update Node-js.